# Using Linq to XML, is it possible to store &quot; in an attribute?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

Using Linq to XML, is it possible to store &quot; in an attribute.

So if I look at the xml source, it will show &quot;

What I've tried so far, is

```
new XAttribute("AttribName", "'")
```

But that just stores '

If I try

```
new XAttribute("AttribName", "&quot;")
```

Then it will store &amp;quot;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first version is an apostrophe, not a quotation mark.  Try this:

```
new XAttribute("name", "\"");
```